# Did Prophet Mohammad (peace be upon him) see Allah (Swt) on Miraj?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, allah, miraj

Did Our Prophet Mohammad (peace be upon Him) see Allah (Swt) with his eyes on Miraj?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it ought to be expressed that your question is counted as a FAQ, since it is considered as the question of many people. God bless you for asking such important question. As you asked

> Did prophet Mohammad peace be upon him see Allah Swt on Miraj

---

**Concise answer:**

As the most related important issue, we should notice that Allah is not body or material. And in truth it is not possible to see Him by vision. Because seeing (by eyes) is related to the material.

On the other hand, seeing which is mentioned in some traditions (hadiths), is related to hearty or sincere seeing, and likewise seeing (or feeling) by the eye of the heart (it is an expression).

E.g. look at the following sentence example:

I saw how much he was talking to his mother in a polite manner.

---

**Conclusion:**

Talking is not see-able, but here it said “I saw how much he was talking…” then it means understanding or hearing or even seeing by the eye of the heart as a kind of feeling. Consequently it can be inferred from the mentioned hadiths that perhaps Prophet Muhammad saw (comprehended or felt) Allah by seeing many facts, wonderful things and signs and so on.

---

**References:**

- [porseman.org](http://porseman.org/q/show.aspx?id=95716)
- [rasoolnoor.com](http://rasoolnoor.com/modules.php?name=Maghaleh&pa=showpage2&pid=78)
- [www.mashreghnews.ir](http://www.mashreghnews.ir/fa/news/62590/%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B5-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC-%DA%86%D9%87-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF)

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. Now i can also refer this information to others so that they understand.

Comment: This answer lacks references. Please post them to enhance it.

Answer (score -1):

It is clear from the Books that the believers will meet Allah hereafter. The only issue that remains is whether it happened in the case of Prophet (s.a.w.s) in this world. It is clear from the descriptions that Prophet (sws) had seen Allah appropriate to  His Majesty. "How" is it, cannot be explained in words.
 Narrated Jarir r:

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) came out to us on the night of the full moon and said, "You will see your Lord on the Day of Resurrection as you see this (full moon) and you will have no difficulty in seeing Him." Saheehul Bhukari-7436.

In the case of Musa a.s. please analyse what Allah said:
"And when Moses arrived at Our appointed time and his Lord spoke to him, he said, "My Lord, show me [Yourself] that I may look at You." [ Allah ] said, "You will not see Me, but look at the mountain; if it should remain in place, then you will see Me." But when his Lord appeared to the mountain, He rendered it level, and Moses fell unconscious. And when he awoke, he said, "Exalted are You! I have repented to You, and I am the first of the believers." - Allah (swt) did not say He can never be seen. The impossibility of seeing from this earth/world only stated. In Mirage, the venue is different. (The Holy Quran 7:143)

Comment: Your example from the Holy Qur'an is for me evidence that Allah swt can not be seen by the means of the eyes.